# Shareable vs Unshared connection in WAS 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, database-connection, connection-pooling

My web app is running on WAS 7.

So, how to decide whether to use Shareable or Unshareable connections to connect to database ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Default behavior of managed connections in WebSphere Application Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0506_johnsen/0506_johnsen.html):

> The use of shareable connections means that, if conditions allow it, different getConnection requests by the application will actually receive a handle (indirectly) for the same physical connection to the resource. The benefits of this are improved performance and a reduction in the number of physical connections that need to be managed.

It is recommended the use of connections shareable, regardless if you call one or more times getConnection within the same global transaction.

Comment: My application is running out of connections during peak load or performance testing

Comment: I am using shareable connection as of now

Comment: In real life, I have rarely had more than 50 concurrent requests. Just make sure to close each connection properly.

Comment: Paul...I am closing all the connections still getting this error

Comment: Did you already increase the connections limit in the pool/database? See http://ibm.co/1OVg7GF

Comment: I have set max connection value to 50